# Creating a gif with gnuplot: Gif doesn't play

Tags: windows, gnuplot, animated-gif

I want to do a gif animation with gnuplot so I wrote:

```
set terminal gif size 1000,800 animate delay 6
set output 'foobar.gif'

set xrange [0:64]
set yrange [0:64]

do for [i=100:5000:100] {
  plot sprintf('folder\name%d.dat',i) u 2:3:(20*$5):(20*$6) with vectors filled head lw 3, 
       sprintf('folder\name%d.dat',i) u 2:3 with points pt 7 ps 2 
}
```

The problem is that, although it doesn't show any error nor warning, when I open the gif file with chrome or ie it doesn't play the gif. What's wrong with it?

I'm using windows 7 x64 with gnuplot 4.6 patch 0. Inside the folder "folder" there is a collection of 50 files that have only 1 line of text. An example of these lines is:

0 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.867146e+00 6.411429e-18 -1.234238e-17 1.106649e-02 8.568272e-18 -9.160938e-18 -3.999043e-18

Comment: Put a `set output` at the end of the script if you plot from the interactive `wgnuplot.exe` command window.

Comment: As @Christoph mentioned, you need to finish with `set output`.  Gnuplot does not always flush its output (even when a script ends).  Sometimes you'll be ok, sometimes you won't.  When you change output destinations, the first thing that gnuplot does is flush any remaining data, thus this command ensures that it is written out.

Comment: There's no change with or without set output at the end of the script. Gif file is created but it only shows the first frame. I run gnuplot from command line.

Comment: Right. It would sound very stupid but I was thinking that I was plotting the correct columns and instead, I was plotting two columns that always have the same value... Thank for your effort.

Comment: Even for a simple question like this, it's always a good idea to give an answer, and stackoverflow gives reputation points for self answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. It would sound very stupid but I was thinking that I was plotting the correct columns and instead, I was plotting two columns that always have the same value... Thank for your effort. –