# Create a gif in Gnuplot from a single file

Tags: gnuplot, gif

I have a long file like the following (I am just writing a sample)

```
0.0 0.00209627946771 6483.0 3092622.0 1100
0.1 0.00253798848144 78.0 30733.0 1100
0.2 0.0174927113703 6.0 343.0 1100
0.3 0.0 0.0 35.0 1100
0.4 0.1 1.0 10.0 1100
0.5 0.0 0.0 4.0 1100
0.9 0.0 0.0 1.0 1100
1.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 1100
0.0 0.00292927058349 9057.0 3091896.0 2100
0.1 0.00299136583044 88.0 29418.0 2100
0.2 0.00743889479277 14.0 1882.0 2100
0.3 0.00578034682081 2.0 346.0 2100
0.4 0.0172413793103 2.0 116.0 2100
0.5 0.030303030303 1.0 33.0 2100
0.6 0.0 0.0 11.0 2100
0.7 0.0 0.0 10.0 2100
0.8 0.0 0.0 11.0 2100
0.9 0.181818181818 2.0 11.0 2100
1.0 0.0 0.0 16.0 2100
0.0 0.00318549549582 9845.0 3090571.0 3100
0.1 0.00273270708796 80.0 29275.0 3100
0.2 0.00489168413697 14.0 2862.0 3100
0.3 0.00810372771475 5.0 617.0 3100
0.4 0.010101010101 2.0 198.0 3100
```

The data I am interested to plot are the first and second column. In the 5th column there is the time of my simulation (it is the information related to the different timestamp).

Tacking inspiration from [Creating a gif with gnuplot: Gif doesn't play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061685/creating-a-gif-with-gnuplot-gif-doesnt-play) I would like to write something like

```
set terminal gif size 1000,800 animate delay 6
set output 'try.gif'

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]

do for [i=100:40200:100] {
 ....
}
```

but I have no idea to how indicate to gnuplot that the i-th  block of data is given by the last column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the timestamps are equidistant. Then you can try something like the following:

```
set terminal gif size 1000, 800 animate delay 100
set output 'try.gif'

# Viewing the 3D plot from top imitates a 2D plot.
set view map

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

do for [i=1100:3100:1000] {
  # Only points at time "i" are plotted.
  set zrange [i-1:i+1]
  set title "Time: ".i
  splot "data.dat" using 1:2:5 w lp
}
```

Tested with Gnuplot 4.6 on Debian Linux. I did not care about performance reading the whole file again and again.

Running the script generates this [image: try.gif]

Answer (score 0):

@maij's solution is a clever way of using `splot` and `zrange` to plot the data for a given time.

Alternatively, here is an automated approach without manually setting a time range and without assuming equidistant time steps.

- get all times values from 5th column via plotting to a table `smooth freq` and `stats` to put the unique time values into a string `TIMES`. This would also work if the times would be disordered.
- use a `do for` loop over `TIMES` and filter your data by `TIME`
- for each iteration you are plotting only a filtered part of the data. Hence, autoscale is not preferred because you (probably) don't want range changes during your animation. Hence, you have to get the x- and y-ranges from an additional `stats` command.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

The script might also work for some gnuplot 4.x versions when using files instead of datablocks.

```
### filter data for an animated gif
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0 0.00209627946771 6483.0 3092622.0 1100
0.1 0.00253798848144 78.0 30733.0 1100
0.2 0.0174927113703 6.0 343.0 1100
0.3 0.0 0.0 35.0 1100
0.4 0.1 1.0 10.0 1100
0.5 0.0 0.0 4.0 1100
0.9 0.0 0.0 1.0 1100
1.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 1100
0.0 0.00292927058349 9057.0 3091896.0 2100
0.1 0.00299136583044 88.0 29418.0 2100
0.2 0.00743889479277 14.0 1882.0 2100
0.3 0.00578034682081 2.0 346.0 2100
0.4 0.0172413793103 2.0 116.0 2100
0.5 0.030303030303 1.0 33.0 2100
0.6 0.0 0.0 11.0 2100
0.7 0.0 0.0 10.0 2100
0.8 0.0 0.0 11.0 2100
0.9 0.181818181818 2.0 11.0 2100
1.0 0.0 0.0 16.0 2100
0.0 0.00318549549582 9845.0 3090571.0 3100
0.1 0.00273270708796 80.0 29275.0 3100
0.2 0.00489168413697 14.0 2862.0 3100
0.3 0.00810372771475 5.0 617.0 3100
0.4 0.010101010101 2.0 198.0 3100
EOD

set table $Temp
    plot $Data u 5 smooth freq
unset table
TIMES = ''
stats $Temp u (TIMES = TIMES.' '.strcol(1)) nooutput

stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput
set xrange[STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x]
set yrange[STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]

myFilter(colD,colF,valF) = column(colF)==valF ? column(colD) : NaN
set datafile missing NaN

set term gif size 640,384 animate delay 100
set output "SO40026393.gif"

do for [TIME in TIMES] {
    set title sprintf("Time: %s", TIME)
    plot $Data u (myFilter(1,5,TIME)):2 w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc "red" title "data"
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]