# gif animation creation with gnuplot, using a single file with keeping previous data on the plot

Tags: gnuplot

This question was answered partly in couple of places, like **[Create a gif in Gnuplot from a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026393/create-a-gif-in-gnuplot-from-a-single-file)**.

Yet there is a problem, the provided answer is going to plot only points at each index.

lets say I have the following data set:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0


0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

my code for creating the gif is :

```
set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output 'foobar.gif'
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
stats 'Datafile' nooutput
do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)] {
   splot  'Datafile' index (i-1) matrix with p ls 1
}
```

This code will generate a gif that just contains the data of each index. while I want the second dataset to be added to the first one the animation.

How should I do that?

Comment: You cannot do this with gnuplot. You must preprocess your data before with an different program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to find the answer by my own, and sorry @Christoph the easiest answer is always erasing the question. Yes it is possible with adding a second loop. I knew that I needed to add a second loop, but I was not sure how to:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output 'foobar.gif'
set grid
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
stats 'Datafile' nooutput
set ztics 1
set zrange [-2:7]
do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)] {
   splot for [j=1:i] 'Datafile' index (j-1) matrix  notitle with p ls 1
}
```

This will generate what I want.

Comment: Ok, then I also had a different understanding of your question. I thought you meant "add" in the sense of summing blocks 1...i.